# how to retrieve a list including and excluding a particular key?

Tags: sql, teradata

i have a table like this where i need to filter on key and retrieve list of keys.

```
id key
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
2   1
2   3
3   1
3   4
4   1
4   4
```

Desired output:

```
id key
2   1
2   3
3   1
3   4
```

Here i want to get a list of id i.e (2,3) in which key 1 is present and key 2 is missing.

Comment: Please clarify "where 1 is there and 2 is not present." According to your "Desired output" section, I would write a WHERE clause such as "WHERE id > 1 AND id < 4", but I feel like that might not solve all of your cases

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli . . . id = 3 doesn't have key = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the question as asked "Here i want to get a list of id . . . in which key 1 is present and key 2 is missing."

You can use `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.key = 1) and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.key = 2);
```

If you just want ids, then I prefer aggregation and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when key = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when key = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: this works fine, it gives me distinct id but when i count them i get all 1's. any idea? also a little explanation would be awesome.

Comment: Are you using `sum()` or `count()`?

Comment: i tried with count and then its giving me all 1's for the id.

Answer (score 0):

suppose your table name is 'testing' then as according to your mentioned output the sql query will be

SELECT * 
FROM  `testing` 
WHERE  `key` !=2 and id in (2,3)